# How can I detect a child element by clicking on a parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a click function for a `parent`element. I want to detect now if the part I clicked has the class "child"

```js
 
$( ".parent" ).click(function() {
    if ( $( this ).hasClass( "child" ) ) {
        console.log("child");
    }   
});
```

```css
.child{background-color:pink}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="parent">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th class="child">Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does the function only have to do something if the clicked element has the class `child`? If so then use event delegation and let jQuery do the work for you: `$(".parent").on("click", ".child", function() { /* <this> is the clicked "child" element */ })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `event.target` to determine the original target of the click:

```js
$(".parent").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass("child")) {
    console.log("child");
  }
});
```

```css
.child {
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="parent">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th class="child">Age</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

access `event.target`, this always references the original target that created the event.

in this case the event started with the `.child` and bubbled up to `.parent` which hit this listener... at this point, `this` and `event.currentTarget` will reference the `.parent` element.. but `target` will still reference the origin element, `.child`.

```
$( ".parent" ).click(function(e) {
    if ( $( e.target ).hasClass( "child" ) ) {
        console.log("child");
    }   
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/99hhn7op/)

Also, unless you have another reason to have the listener on `.parent`, you could just add the listener directly to the child like this:

```
$( ".parent .child" ).click(function() {
    console.log("child");
});
```